# How to close open files after processing.runalg() command (Qgis: Error No 24)

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, qgis-processing, saga

I'm creating a pyqgis script. In this script I use the **processing.runalg** command several times. The problem is that these processes are within a for loop. After several iterations, the **error number 24** "too many open file" appears. How can I close the files generated by the processes? Here is an example of the code:

> for i in range (1, 13000):
>
> ```
> path1 = '/path/to/file1_' + str(i) + '.shp'
> path2 = '/path/to/file2_' + str(i) + '.shp'
> path3 = '/path/to/file3_' + str(i) + '.asc'
> path4 = '/path/to/file4_' + str(i) + '.asc'
> path5 = '/path/to/file5_' + str(i) + '.shp'
> path6 = '/path/to/file6_' + str(i) + '.shp'
> path7 = '/path/to/file7_' + str(i) + '.asc'
> path8 = '/path/to/file8_' + str(i) + '.asc'
>
> processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', path1,'EPSG:3004',path2)
> processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', path5,'EPSG:3004',path6)
>
> processing.runalg('saga:cubicsplineapproximation', path2,'field',3.0,20.0,5.0,140.0,'2596187,2675187,4321914,4403914',1000.0,0,path3)
> processing.runalg('saga:cubicsplineapproximation', path6,'field',3.0,20.0,5.0,140.0,'2596187,2675187,4321914,4403914',1000.0,0,path7)
>
> processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent', path3,'-9999','2611187.7500000000000000,2660187.7500000000000000,4336914.1990000000223517,4388914.1990000000223517',5,4,75.0,6.0,1.0,False,0,False,None,path4)
> processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent', path7,'-9999','2611187.7500000000000000,2660187.7500000000000000,4336914.1990000000223517,4388914.1990000000223517',5,4,75.0,6.0,1.0,False,0,False,None,path8)
> ...     ...
> ```

Comment: I'm guessing it's somewhat related to [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8325). What about assigning a name to each process and deleting this (i.e. `output_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', path1,'EPSG:3004',path2`, then after this line add `del output_1`)? Another approach could be to load the result of each process and then remove them all at the end of each iteration (i.e. `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers([layers.id()])`

Comment: @Joseph I've already tried this solution but it doesn' t work. I checked and the files are open until QGIS is closed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when running a `for loop` of more than 160 itens in Python Console at QGis 2.18.17. I could manage it setting the number of files opened by process using `ulimit` command at Linux terminal before opening Qgis at the same terminal. Take a look at this link: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/preamble/features.html#python-console
I hope it can help you.